# How to understand vue router navigation?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am working with this piece of code:

```
<script>
    import router from '../router'

    export default {
        name: 'Page2',
        data () {
            return {
                id: 0,
                msg: 'Hey Nic Raboy'
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.id = this.$route.params.id;
        },
        methods: {
            navigate() {
                router.go(-1);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is printed on the second page Template B if you will but I am confused on the navigate portion. Specifically this:

```
navigate() {
  router.go(-1);
}
```

I have not worked with VueJS router before, can anyone please explain what this code section does?

Answer (score 3):

Vue-router package works in the same way with the HTML5 History mode as it stated in the [vue-router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

> This method takes a single integer as parameter that indicates by how
>   many steps to go forwards or go backwards in the history stack,
>   similar to window.history.go(n).

So basically this is what you should expect from router.go()

```
// go back by one record, the same as history.back()
router.go(-1)
```

You can also learn more about HTML5 History mode from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [router.go(n)](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-go-n) documentation in the section on [programmatic navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#programmatic-navigation). The example explains that `n` can be positive or negative and indicates the number of steps in the browser's history to move.

```
// go forward by one record, the same as history.forward()
router.go(1)

// go back by one record, the same as history.back()
router.go(-1)
```

So `router.go(-1)` is the equivalent of hitting the "back" button in your browser.